# HttpClient.GetAsync() hangs until timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, ef-core-5.0

I want to get movie image link form TMDB website. I'm using Entity Framework Core 5, MVC

But when I am making API call in getImageLink() method and it will not go past this line:

> var task = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

Im assuming the problem might be related to deadlocking or having HttpClient in using

> using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())

It worked fine few days ago, but when I launched it today, it was not working (I didn't change anything)

Movie proporties:

```
    public int id { get; set; }

    //Movie info properties
    [Column("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("year")]
    public int year { get; set; }
    [Column("overview")]
    public string overview { get; set; }

    //NotMapped properties
    [NotMapped]
    public string imageLink { get { return getImageLink().Result; } }
```

id, title, year and overview are stored in postgre database.

getMovieLink method:

```
private async Task<string> getImageLink()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string key = Data.APIKeys.TheMovieDB_api_key;
            string url = $"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={key}&query={title}";
            string imageLink = "https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2";
            var task = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (task.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var jsonString = content.Result;
                var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
                var linqList = parsedObject.SelectToken("results").ToArray();
                foreach (var linq in linqList)
                {
                    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(linq.ToString());
                    if (obj["title"].ToString() == title && obj["release_date"].ToString().Substring(0, 4) == year.ToString())
                    {
                        imageLink += obj["poster_path"].ToString();
                        return imageLink;
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Error screenshot:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snwpY.png)

Comment: Have you tested the URL manually to see how long it takes from your browser?

Comment: As a side note, it would be preferable to have your controller invoke `getImageLink()` using `await` and then put the returned string onto the model property, rather than having the property getter call it and block on the `.Result`.

Comment: As some of the answers mentioned. It's probably not your code, although it can be improved.  There was a database outage.

Answer (score 2):

You're unlucky as you've unfortunately hit **an ongoing AWS outage, which is also affecting TMDB which most likely runs on AWS's infrastructure**.

The [Wappalyzer report](http://wappalyzer.com/lookup/themoviedb.org) lists *PaaS* as *Amazon Web Services* & *CDN* as *Amazon CloudFront*.

AWS powers a *lot* of the internet as a quick Google search for *AWS outage* will show.

Considering the same code was working previously, I'd check [AWS's status page](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) regularly for the latest updates until all issues are resolved. Even if they don't definitely use AWS, something that they use probably will.

---

P.S. `task.IsSuccessStatusCode` won't always be true even for the most stable of APIs.

Write an `else` statement to accompany your `if` statement and actually handle errors gracefully.

Comment: @TomTom That too yes - and don't use `.Result` but the answer to their question is that it's not their fault ;)

Comment: I am using themoviedb.org, not IMDb. Or TMDb is also using amazon servers? Thanks for answers, I will add else statement as well as decreasing timeout time.

Comment: @sulya Ah - my bad. Updated the answer